# find the day according to the date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The only thing new here is the use of `eval()`:

```
myDate=new Date(eval('"'+aText.value+'"'))
```

We need the date with quotes around it, but, as it appears in the box, it does not have any. So we add the quotes. But this makes a mere string, and we want a `Date` object. So we use `eval()` to make the changes.

It's not giving the right answer

```
function getTheDay(aText)
{

    myDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    console.log(eval('"' + aText.value + '"'));
    myDate = new Date(eval('"' + aText.value + '"'))
    console.log(myDate)
    document.write(myDays[myDate.getDay()], "day");

}
```

Comment: DO NOT USE eval() ! It poses a dangerous security risk.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: but eval will evaluate my date ?

Comment: No `eval()` invokes the Javascript compiler to EXECUTE CODE, which could be malicious if someone uses script injection.

Comment: what is the exact content of `aText.value` please?

Comment: its the date... which i pass through a string

Comment: @AlexW Honestly, in this case there's not really any security risk: somebody can edit the code in the console just as easily as they can put javascript into a textbox. The problem here is more that it's slow, inefficient, and unreadable.

Comment: Your use of `eval` seems exceedingly unnecessary. What kind of data is in `aText.value`?

Comment: i thought that i will add teh date.... but now i can understand the problem. actually i want the day to be calculated when i write the date like 25 December, 2000

Comment: @PeterOlson Let's say that it's not a risk in this case, and so it's left in the script and then someone comes along later and doesn't notice the eval in the code and passes their input to the `getTheDay(aText)` function. Then it's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function getTheDay(dateText) {
    myDays = [
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday"];

    return myDays[new Date(dateText).getDay()];
}

document.write(getTheDay(aText.value));
```

You are overcomplicating this by using `eval()`.  There is absolutely no reason you should have to use `eval()` to make this work.

Note that JavaScript expects dates to be in a [specific format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14).  If the value the user has typed into the `aText` control does not match this format then you will either get a runtime exception or the constructed Date object will not have the value you expect.

Comment: hey it doea work... just in the last line its document.write(getTheDay(aText)

Comment: If `aText` is already a string, then yes, just `aText`.  If `aText` refers to an `<input>` element then it needs to be `aText.value`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing `eval('"'+aText.value+'"')`?

`aText.value` is a string.  You can just do `new Date(aText.value)`.

```
var myDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var myDate = new Date(aText.value);
console.log(myDays[myDate.getDay()]);
```

**NOTE**: You don't need to "add quotes" to variables to make then strings, that's not how variables work.

```
var a = 'hello world';
var b = a;  // a is a string variable.  no need to add quotes or "eval"
```

Comment: What is `var myDate = myDate;` supposed to do?

Comment: @cdhowie: That would be a typo X_X

Comment: thanx...
this gave me the write code


 function getTheDay(aText) {
    myDays = [
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday"];

    

console.log(myDays[new Date(aText).getDay()],"my day")
return myDays[new Date(aText.value).getDay()];

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `eval` for that...almost any normally formatted date should work.

`new Date('June 28, 2006')`
Wed Jun 28 2006 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)